# Format Time using strtime for google format

Tags: ruby

How can I use strftime to get this date format:

```
2013-12-17T00:00:00
```

I know I can use strftime but I am strugging getting this exact format that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = Time.utc(2013,12,17)
t.strftime('%FT%T') # '2013-12-17T00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):004:0> DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
=> "2013-12-17T16:50:43"
irb(main):005:0> Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
=> "2013-12-17T00:00:00"
```